# Convert list/vector of string to nested list based on matching pattern

Tags: r

Let's say I have this vector:

```
dummyvector <- c("/path/to/b2:banana.txt","/path/to/a1:apple.txt",
"/path/to/b1:apple.txt","/path/to/c2:banana.txt")
```

And I want a list with the key based on the string after colon and before .txt:

```
$apple
[1] "/path/to/a1:apple.txt" "/path/to/b1:apple.txt"

$banana
[1] "/path/to/b2:banana.txt" "/path/to/c2:banana.txt"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use `base::basename()` to extract the filename portion of the paths.
`stringr::str_extract()` with some RegEx groups lets us extract only the name
of the fruit. We use the resulting vector to `base::split()` the original vector.

```r
library(stringr)
dummyvector <- c("/path/to/b2:banana.txt","/path/to/a1:apple.txt",
                 "/path/to/b1:apple.txt","/path/to/c2:banana.txt")

dummyvector_names <- 
  dummyvector |> 
  basename() |> 
  str_extract("(:)([a-z]+)", group = 2)

split(dummyvector, 
      dummyvector_names)
#> $apple
#> [1] "/path/to/a1:apple.txt" "/path/to/b1:apple.txt"
#> 
#> $banana
#> [1] "/path/to/b2:banana.txt" "/path/to/c2:banana.txt"
```